# function to determine change point dates

Tags: pandas

I'm working with some time series data, and would like to create a function that identifies change points for a metric. In this case, the change point would be whenever the 7D moving average crosses the 30D moving average.

In my df, I would like to be able to flag these dates, and compute rolling calculations pinned to the change date. For instance, cumulative delta/pct change/etc.

I have some rather ugly code that gets me most of the way there. However would like to know from the community if there are ways of doing this without creating intermediary columns.

```
data = {'rpc_avg_7d': {(48, '2018-11-26'): 2.8,
  (48, '2018-11-27'): 2.75,
  (48, '2018-11-28'): 2.62,
  (48, '2018-11-29'): 2.48,
  (48, '2018-11-30'): 2.39,
  (48, '2018-12-01'): 2.41,
  (48, '2018-12-02'): 2.46,
  (49, '2018-12-04'): 2.56,
  (49, '2018-12-05'): 2.73,
  (49, '2018-12-06'): 2.86,
  (49, '2018-12-07'): 3.01,
  (49, '2018-12-08'): 3.09,
  (49, '2018-12-09'): 3.2,
  (50, '2018-12-10'): 3.36,
  (50, '2018-12-11'): 3.4,
  (50, '2018-12-12'): 3.36,
  (50, '2018-12-13'): 3.43},
 'rpc_avg_30d': {(48, '2018-11-26'): 2.76,
  (48, '2018-11-27'): 2.77,
  (48, '2018-11-28'): 2.76,
  (48, '2018-11-29'): 2.76,
  (48, '2018-11-30'): 2.74,
  (48, '2018-12-01'): 2.73,
  (48, '2018-12-02'): 2.71,
  (49, '2018-12-04'): 2.73,
  (49, '2018-12-05'): 2.78,
  (49, '2018-12-06'): 2.79,
  (49, '2018-12-07'): 2.8,
  (49, '2018-12-08'): 2.8,
  (49, '2018-12-09'): 2.82,
  (50, '2018-12-10'): 2.83,
  (50, '2018-12-11'): 2.87,
  (50, '2018-12-12'): 2.91,
  (50, '2018-12-13'): 2.94},
 'MA_diff': {(48, '2018-11-26'): 0.04,
  (48, '2018-11-27'): -0.02,
  (48, '2018-11-28'): -0.14,
  (48, '2018-11-29'): -0.27,
  (48, '2018-11-30'): -0.35,
  (48, '2018-12-01'): -0.32,
  (48, '2018-12-02'): -0.25,
  (49, '2018-12-04'): -0.18,
  (49, '2018-12-05'): -0.05,
  (49, '2018-12-06'): 0.08,
  (49, '2018-12-07'): 0.21,
  (49, '2018-12-08'): 0.29,
  (49, '2018-12-09'): 0.38,
  (50, '2018-12-10'): 0.53,
  (50, '2018-12-11'): 0.54,
  (50, '2018-12-12'): 0.45,
  (50, '2018-12-13'): 0.48}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['trend_flag'] = df['MA_diff'].transform(lambda x: 'up' if x > 0 else 'down')
df['change_pt'] = df['trend_flag'] != df['trend_flag'].shift(1)
print(df)

               rpc_avg_7d  rpc_avg_30d  MA_diff trend_flag  change_pt
48 2018-11-26        2.80         2.76     0.04         up       True
   2018-11-27        2.75         2.77    -0.02       down       True
   2018-11-28        2.62         2.76    -0.14       down      False
   2018-11-29        2.48         2.76    -0.27       down      False
   2018-11-30        2.39         2.74    -0.35       down      False
   2018-12-01        2.41         2.73    -0.32       down      False
   2018-12-02        2.46         2.71    -0.25       down      False
49 2018-12-04        2.56         2.73    -0.18       down      False
   2018-12-05        2.73         2.78    -0.05       down      False
   2018-12-06        2.86         2.79     0.08         up       True
   2018-12-07        3.01         2.80     0.21         up      False
   2018-12-08        3.09         2.80     0.29         up      False
   2018-12-09        3.20         2.82     0.38         up      False
50 2018-12-10        3.36         2.83     0.53         up      False
   2018-12-11        3.40         2.87     0.54         up      False
   2018-12-12        3.36         2.91     0.45         up      False
   2018-12-13        3.43         2.94     0.48         up      False
```

I am not able to figure out how to use a function to pass in the (2nd) level (date) of the multi-index when `change_pt==True`.

Bonus points - can anyone explain what the general concept is that would allow you to tie rolling calculations to arbitrary/calculated dates within  time series groups? This could potentially work by grouping by [change_pt,date] and applying `.rolling`, but this seems messy.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you could do this:

```
df['change_point_date'] = np.where(np.sign(df['MA_diff']) != np.sign(df['MA_diff'].shift(1)), df.index.get_level_values(1), None)
```

Which compares the sign of the current `MA_diff` with the sign of the previous, and if they are different, outputs the value of level 1 of the multiindex.

The tail of the new df:

```
               rpc_avg_7d  rpc_avg_30d  MA_diff change_point_date
49 2018-12-04        2.56         2.73    -0.18              None
   2018-12-05        2.73         2.78    -0.05              None
   2018-12-06        2.86         2.79     0.08        2018-12-06
   2018-12-07        3.01         2.80     0.21              None
   2018-12-08        3.09         2.80     0.29              None
   2018-12-09        3.20         2.82     0.38              None
50 2018-12-10        3.36         2.83     0.53              None
   2018-12-11        3.40         2.87     0.54              None
   2018-12-12        3.36         2.91     0.45              None
   2018-12-13        3.43         2.94     0.48              None
```

Comment: this is great, thank you. i wasn't aware of how to set values that way. I think all i need to do now is fill/broadcast these values and calculate a date offset for each.

Comment: If you post your desired output for that bit can help out.

Comment: i'm actually not sure of the output i want yet, as there could be better ways of doing this without explicitly defining the columns
An example of the information i'd like to calculate is:

As of 12-13, Group XX has been trending upward for 8 days since 12-06. The 7dMA has increased by 20% and is 17% higher than the 30dMA